# Copying tables across documents adds extra high row height

Tags: microsoft-word, copy-paste, text-formatting

I'm copying word tables from one Word document to another Word document. I would prefer to use Excel but these MUST be in Word.

The original tables were all formatted correctly with the row height appropriate for the text size (7-11 pt).

Copying the tables into a report, all of a sudden the text remains the same size but the cell width is for something about font 50. Highlighting the text is also strange as there is extra space of highlighting above and below the small text as if it was font 50.

What is also strange is I am unable to lower the row height manually. I can make it wider, but not narrower. Columns are not affected.

I've tried using format painter but no luck. I tried creating a new document and copying into it and it copies fine. Copied new document table to where I want it to go and same problem as before.

I've toyed with all the settings in the table properties and no luck.

This also seems to be happening when copying the tables on a Word 2010 PC.

Comment: When you paste the table are you using source formatting or merge formatting?

Comment: I don't know. I'm just copying and pasting. I've tried some of the paste special option but I don't want the word doc embedded or a picture.

Comment: Make sure your page formatting is the same. If one has significantly larger margins, it may mess with the table formatting. Also when you paste, try the `keep source formatting` to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Keeping source formatting seems to be doing the trick! Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is confusing. The question talks about high, wide and narrow; height and width; and above and below.  Is the problem *both* height and width?  And you say the problem *also* occurs with Word 2010 — what version of Word were you talking about in the first six paragraphs? … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.  Consider using the specific [microsoft-word-NNNN] tag(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your page formatting is the same. If one has significantly larger margins, it may mess with the table formatting.

Also when you paste, try the `keep source formatting` to see if that resolves the issue.